# How do i check if a string has a certain number of letters and digits?

Tags: c++, string, function

I need to create a function to check if the string I send as a parameter has the first 4 characters as a letter, and the last 3 are digits, and that it has exactly 7 characters. How would I code this function?

Comment: Could use a regex: `[A-Za-z]{4}[0-9]{3}`

Comment: Haven't learned regex in my class yet, mainly have to use basic things, such as things included in the string library.

Comment: `std::string::length()` to check the length is 7, and `std::count_if()` to check a range of characters contains the expected number of letters and digts.  Or use a regular expression library.

Comment: You'll have more chance of getting help if you demonstrate a genuine attempt to design and code your function.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a coding solution to a trivial problem, with no evidence of any effort other than posting the question.

Comment: Attending your classes and reading the textbook could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to loop through the string checking each individual character, eg:

```
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

bool is4LettersAnd3Digits(const std::string &s)
{
    if (s.length() != 7)
        return false;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        if (!std::isalpha(s[i]))
            return false;
    }

    for (int i = 4; i < 7; ++i) {
        if (!std::isdigit(s[i]))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Alternatively:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

bool is4LettersAnd3Digits(const std::string &s)
{
    return (
        (s.length() == 7) &&
        (std::count_if(s.begin(), s.begin()+4, std::isalpha) == 4) &&
        (std::count_if(s.begin()+4, s.end(), std::isdigit) == 3)
    );
}
```

Alternatively, if using C++11 or later:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

bool is4LettersAnd3Digits(const std::string &s)
{
    if (
        (s.length() == 7) &&
        std::all_of(s.begin(), s.begin()+4, std::isalpha) &&
        std::all_of(s.begin()+4, s.end(), std::isdigit)
    );
}
```

Comment: I'd replace `std::count_if` with `std::all_of`.

Comment: @lisyarus `std::all_of()` is new in C++11. `std::count_if()` exists in earlier versions. I have updated my answer, though.

Comment: Whilst I perfectly understand that there do exist environments with C++11 unavailable, it sounds logical to assume the current official standard of C++ language by default, which is currently C++14. If one has to use older versions, this should be clearly stated in the question.
Apart from this, nice answer!

Comment: @lisyarus A lot of environments haven't adopted C++11 yet, let alone C++14 or even C++17. C++11/14 may be the current, but it is not widespread. But I do agree that questions should be marked accordingly.